# Modern C++ way to repeat code for set number of times

Tags: c++, loops, c++17, c++20

Very simply, is there a simpler way to repeat a block for a certain number of times, where the block inside does not need the counter variable? The trivial solution is of course

```
for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
  //do your thing, i is not used here
}
```

However, now that we have ranged for, standard algorithms and other fancy constructs for iterating over containers, in comparison this is actually starting to feel like a lot of boilerplate and details for what should be an even simpler case. For example we're not interested in the variable `i` at all etc.

The closest thing to a concrete problem is this: when I encounter a for loop such as above, I need to scan through the code block to see if `i` is actually used, or if it's just a dummy counter. The declaration of a for loop which actually wants to do something with the integers 0 to `repetitions - 1` will look identical. So a `repeat (n)` -type construct would have the extra semantic information that all the iterations will be the same, except for potential side-effects.

One option is to make a template

```
template<class functor>
repeat(functor fun, unsigned n) {
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     fun();
}
```

and call

```
repeat([&](){
  //do your thing
}, repetitions)
```

but this really seems like overengineered overkill for a simple problem. This could be macroized to make the usage a bit nicer, but that certainly won't help with the overengineered feel.

So one valid answer is that I'm on a wild goose chase here, and should just use the good old for loop with counter.

Any standard C++ is fine, including upcoming standards.

Related questions such as [How to create a loop in C++ that loops a certain amount of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401678/how-to-create-a-loop-in-c-that-loops-a-certain-amount-of-times)  and [How to create a loop in C++ that loops a certain amount of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401678/how-to-create-a-loop-in-c-that-loops-a-certain-amount-of-times) are beginners asking for some way to achieve this, whereas I'm specifically asking for a modern, clean and elegant way to achieve this. [c++ repeat N iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924901/c-repeat-n-iterations) is very close, though the difference here is that I'm asking for any alternatives, not necessarily included in `std::`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ repeat N iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924901/c-repeat-n-iterations)

Comment: Well...a simple function abstracting the loop may be enough. But still I see no problem on having old trusty loops.

Comment: Is there any problem with a normal loop? C++ even allows declaring counter inside of it.

Comment: @VTT no, no actual problem of course. This is more about me nerdsniping myself about trying to write things in the simplest possible way, which expresses intent most directly.

Comment: @cfillion you're right, I somehow missed that! I'm tempted to delete my question now, however, there does seem to be commentary, an answer and a few upvotes already...

Comment: @Timo *"write things in the simplest possible way, which expresses intent most directly"* - then you should certainly try using COBOL: `Perform something 5 times.`

Comment: Embarrassing comment... Back to the good old macro: `#define TIMES(N) int i = 0 ; i < N; ++i` and use `for(TIMES(10)) std::cout << i << "\n";` or even: `#define REPEAT(N) for(size_t i = 0 ; i < N; ++i)` and use `REPEAT(10) std::cout << i << "\n";`

Comment: You have to first come up with a convincing reason why a for loop is problematic, without such you are fixing what is not broken. You might as well ask for having a "modern way" to add two ints.

Comment: @VTT I'll start looking for a COBOL compiler for the STM32 -series... :D More seriosuly, probably the closest thing to a concrete problem with the standard for loop used for this purpose is this: when I see `for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {...}`, I need to scan through the block of code to see if `i` is actually used in the loop, or if it's just a dummy counter.

Comment: @PasserBy see the edit

Comment: @Timo You can name it appropriately instead of using meaningless name such as `i`. I would write `for(auto remaining_iterations_count{iterations_count}; 0 < remaining_iterations_count; --remaining_iterations_count)` if that counter is not used in the loop or `for(decltype(iterations_count) iteration_index{}; iteration_index < iterations_count; ++iteration_index)` if that index is supposed to be used inside of loop. PS COBOL syntax is underrated.

Answer (score 6):

#### Introduction

Modern does not necessarily means using newest feautures.

#### Solution

One of the easiest solutions it to use simple [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) loop as below:

```
for (auto _ = times; _--;) [[likely]] statement;
```

…where:

- `times` is a constant [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) with no suffix (*ie* 3).
- `statement` is a [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) to be executed `times` times.

#### Example

Example usage:

```
constexpr auto f(int Value) noexcept
{
    for (auto _ = 3; _--;) [[likely]] ++Value;
    return Value;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto i = f(2);
    return i;
}
```

Constant `i` variable is declared with initial value of `2`, increased 3 times by one in `f`'s `for` loop, taking final value of `5` and being used as program returned value.

#### Notes

- Some compiler implementations may potentially take use of [`[[likely]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) attribute in future.
  If `times` constant is likely to be zero, use `[[unlikely]]` attribute instead.
  Likelihood attribute is a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) feauture, skip in earlier versions.
- `_` name is commonly used as meaningless to name a discardable variable.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a modern C++ way, how about an old C way but without an index:

```
while (repetitions--)
    fun();
```

Of course you still need a variable for `repetitions` though.

Comment: `repetitions` *is* an index

Comment: related: [What is the --> operator in `while (repetitions --> 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/5470596) :D

Comment: In my opinion, defining a counter is completely inconsistent with human thinking.I gave my suggestion related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654319/why-c-has-no-concise-syntax-that-allow-executing-an-operation-multiple-times-w.

Answer (score 0):

"Hand-made" `repeat` is somewhat problematic. Should there be `break` or `continue`? One can throw an exception from "inside" repat, and "break out". But some projects do disallow exceptions.

Also in the presence of a standard `for range loop` one does not need to "*scan through the code block to see if i is actually used, or if it's just a dummy counter.*". That argument is done with.

To have compiler intrinsic `repeat` might be not such a bad idea, and certainly would be easy to add.

```
    // C++ 25 -- perhaps 
    repeat( 42 ) {
        std::printf("\nThis is 42 lines of text.");
        continue; // allowed
        break ;   // allowed
    }
```

REPEAT(N) macro is tempting, but macros are forbiden. If not compiler intrinsic, user defined `repeat` is not that "simple and elegant". Here is what I might be using:

```
// the repeat
template< typename CALLABLE_, typename ... Args >
void repeat( size_t N, CALLABLE_ fun_, Args ... args)
{
    for ( auto k = 0 ; k <  N ; k++ ) {
        fun_(args ...);
    }
}
```

Now to use the above one would most likely call it with lambda. Usage is as expected:

```
// reachable from inside `repeat`
int result {} ;

repeat( 0xF ,  
 [&] {  
     ::std::wprintf( L"\n random word:\t '%s'", random_word());
     result++ ;
    }
 );
```

The "modern way" is not always "the elegant vintage way".